# trouble with nested layouts

Tags: android, layout

I'm just beginning Android and have gotten myself stuck.  I've made a simple app/view.  The idea is draw a line-maze in the top, with motion buttons on the bottom.  My app only draws an x with a couple lines in the frame, but that works.  The problem is that my buttons are being drawn too far down, and are clipped in height.

I assume the problem is all in my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" > 

            <none.maze.MazeView
             android:id="@+id/maze"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:text="@string/maze_layout_text_text"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#ff8888ff"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >             

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Left" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/forward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Forward" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Right" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use `layout_height="fill_parent"` and `layout_weight` at the same time. Try to set `layout_height="0dip"` and `layout_weight="1"` for the `FrameLayout` and `layout_height="wrap_content"` for the lower `LinearLayout`. The lower `LinearLayout` mustn't have the `layout_weight` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to debug your layout. Its pretty cool.

Comment: That is cool, I'll remember it.  This time things were in the right place, so they 'looked right' in the viewer.

Comment: Note that hierarchy viewer doesn't work on production builds (of the OS, not your app). It will fail with a "hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device" message. You can use it on emulated devices if you don't have a debug build on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire layout is just way too bloated and ineffective. You use way too many `ViewGroup`s. I recommend reading about `RelativeLayout`s and especially the entire [Layout Tricks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) series.

Comment: The only flaw I see with his layouts is a `Button` nested into `RelativeLayout`. In this case it's used to center the button, but it's not needed as the `FrameLayout` can do the same if he'd specified `layout_gravity="center"` for the button. In all other ways his layout is good. The rule of thumb: you should avoid using RelativeLayout if you can use 2 nested LinearLayout to achieve the same. Nested layouts used to cause StackOverflowException **in the past** due to the faulty design, but that's **in the past now**. In the same time, LinearLayouts are much MUCH easier to maintain.

Comment: @JBM Speaking of _in the past_, did you notice the answer date?

Comment: Did you come back after ~2 years just to dismiss my comment? :) :) :)

Comment: The question and answer are still here to be found and read, and to help or mislead, and it looks like the comment is more currently useful than the answer. Though what would be extra useful - did the transition occur with a particular Android version (so developing for old versions could still need the old approach) or with a bugfix that's included when developing for any Android version?